# Running a build pipeline AFTER my code has been merged?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'll do my best to explain my problem.

In standard practice, I have an Azure Devops pipeline that creates a Terraform payload, invokes Terraform API, and lets Terraform do its deployment based off the payload. I do this by "Build Validation" - whenever something is PR'd into my branch, the pipeline runs to make sure I'm deploying proper Terraform infrastructure, and in the process, deploys said resources if the pipeline runs succeeds.

Meaning, the current workflow is:

**Incoming PR -> Build Valdiation starts -> Pipeline runs -> Pipeline run succeeds -> Accept the PR and do a merge**

However, the team I'm working with now wants the following:

**Incoming PR -> Accept the PR and do a merge -> Build Validation starts -> Pipeline runs -> Pipeline run succeeds**

Basically, they want to actually review the incoming PR, accept and merge it, and ONLY THEN have the actual pipeline/deployment process start. And I'm not sure how to perform this step. Looking into CI triggers, I couldn't find what I need. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try setting up a branch policy on the branch where you want to merge your PR. It will enforce you to make a PR to merge code into that branch. Here is a url to a video explaining it: https://youtu.be/2nukM2TzD1Q

Comment: Define a build strategy based on your branch. This will trigger the pipeline only when the merge occurs. For example lets say you have `feature/1` branch and your master  branch. Define `trigger: master` and then the pipeline will run only when the PR is merged into your master

Comment: The issue I see with what the team wants is that if the build validation fails, rolling back those changes will be cumbersome as the merge will already be done. There might be other reasons for this but to me the initial flow you proposed is more logic.

Now it seems your "build validation" (on PR) is deploying terraform resources ? That also seems curious, I would see that triggered after the merge in a seperate build / pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you need to use the [CI trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers).

Assuming they merge is to `master` branch and you want to run the pipeline **after** the merge add to the yaml the `trigger`:

```
trigger:
- master
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same earlier. Unfortunately, azure does not offer anything like this.
I think the easiest solution is to set up a protected intermediate branch. E.g. `pre-master` and then make pr's towards this one and disallow humanly issued master merges. Then, as proposed by others, set a trigger on `pre-merge` after which you then commit to the master.
You can then complete the ping-pong by defining a trigger on `master` that aligns `pre-master` afterwards.